# Morris.Donut set data for label and the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have a Morris donut/pie char that I initialize like following:

```
function InitializePieChart(data) {
    var formedData = "";
    var length = Object.keys(data).length;
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        if (index === (length - 1)) {
            formedData += "{ value: '"+value.Percentage+"' , label: '" + value.SellerName + "' }";
        }
        else {
            formedData += "{ value: '"+ value.Percentage + "' , label: '"+ value.SellerName + "' } , ";
        }
    });
    console.log(formedData);
    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'pie-chart',
        data: [JSON.stringify(formedData)],
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        labelColor: '#6d6d6d',
        colors: [
            '#012e42',
            '#076178',
            '#0f7c93',
            '#1b99ac'
        ],
        formatter: function (x) { return x + " %" }
    });
}
```

As you can see here the value for the donut chart should be set to the "Percentage" property of the returned JSON, and the label should be set to the "SellerName" property...

However whatever I tried didn't work.. The returned JSON contains more properties than these two but they are irrelevant for this chart... I tried forming a JSON to inject it into the chart , but it returns as empty when the page is rendered completely..

Is there any way I can just simply inject the data into chart directly and then specify which property belongs to "label" and which belongs to "value" ?

Can someone help me out with this one?